# БД: как организовать подсчет объктов в базе данных исходя из условий?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос методологичейский из разряда, как правильно сделать.

Есть доска объявлений по продаже авто, которая имеет 230 марок и 1500 моделей автомобилей.

Всего порядка 300 городов где представлены объявления о продаже.

Таким образом, есть 4 таблицы: марки, модели, города, объявления.

Когда пользователь заходит на страницу города, например, Хабаровск, он видит список марок авто и подсчитанное количество объявлений для каждой марки для этого города.

Сейчас это количество объявлений считается через count в таблице с объявлениями. Каждый раз отдельный запрос при обращении к странице.

Поскольку городов очень много, а таблица с объявлениями станет большой и у меня вопрос:

Как лучше организовать подсчет количества объявлений для марок и моделей для **каждого** города в этом случае?

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает вариант `select count(*) from объявления where город_id = 8 and марк_id = 7 and модел_id = 6 `?

Comment: @Victor марки/модели считаются через Having count. Запрос занимает 1,5 сек.

Comment: не плохо было бы привести пример запроса

Comment: @Victor `select tbl.title, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM adds as a WHERE tbl.id = a.id_vendor) as count_vendor FROM vendors as tbl HAVING count_vendor > 0`

Comment: попробуйте так `select TBL.TITLE, count(A.id) as count_vendor
from VENDORS as TBL
left join ADDS as A on A.ID_VENDOR = TBL.ID
group by TBL.TITLE
having count(A.id) > 0` по идее в этом случае даже не потребуется хевинг, но сейчас с утра не соображу так это или нет!

Comment: Это тот случай, когда ради ускорения запросто можно допустить незначительную некорректность данных (ну покажет в общей таблице, что есть 5 объявлений, а при детальном выводе их окажется только 4 - ерунда в общем...) и пойти по пути предрасчёта объявлений для города (скажем, реализованную на триггерах, либо брать статические данные предыдущего расчёта при соблюдении условия актуальности).

Comment: @Victor, Спасибо за помощь! Буду всё-таки делать отдельную таблицу!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы не хотите каждый раз делать "громоздкий" запрос на выборку кол-ва объявлений, можете создать еще одну таблицу в которой будут хранится кол-во объявлений для каждого города, марки, модели или чего там нужно. Добавить триггер на вставку и удаление в таблице `объявления`, который соответственно, при вставке или удалении будет увеличивать(уменьшать) счетчик записей в таблице `кол-во объявлений`